# install gcc and g++

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies, gcc, g++

I tried all the commands

```
sudo apt-get build-dep build-essential
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install g++
```

But all time I am getting this error.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 build-essential : Depends: gcc (>= 4:4.4.3) but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: g++ (>= 4:4.4.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Build-dependencies for build-essential could not be satisfied.
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @blade19899 yes also tried

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -f` is also something one uses in this case

Comment: i tried but getting same error.

Comment: Please see this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

The command build-dep is used to install the dependencies of a package that you want to compile from source. Have you tried to execute

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

?

Comment: yes i tried this one too but getting same error.

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you using? Is it a clean install or you've modified anything that could be relevant for package retrieval and installation (such as software repositories)?

Comment: i am using 13.10 version. i tried installation of codeblock but quit it in the middle after that i tried a lot but getting same error.

Comment: are you using any extra package repository other than the default ones? If yes try to disable them, run `sudo apt-get update` and then try again to install the packages